Azure Data Explorer: RLS using external metadata
I was wondering what the best approach would be to implement RLS for this kind of data. I'm simply exploring options here, so if the answer is it's not possible, then that is that.
A little description of the data

It doesn't have any column that represents an AD group, it only has a unique guididentifier
At any given time, new guid can appear in the table

Now the issue is, user A which is apart of some group B with GroupID is querying the data. I want to apply RLS where group B is only allowed to see data for specific GUID (which, according to 2 can change).
Is there any way of doing this? Like having a external table hold the Group-GUID pairs and use that for joining / filtering the query?
Or am I stuck because I would need to include the GroupID as a column in the query and since my data already doesn't include that column, then there is no way for me to add it post-ingestion?

To enforce row-level security (RLS) in Azure Data Explorer (ADX) using external metadata, consider adding a column for AD groups to your data or creating multiple tables with distinct GUIDs and assigning permissions accordingly. This approach enhances query performance and enables tailored data access based on user groups. see the Apply row-level security on SQL external tables documentation.

Maybe it is possible to put the GUID in a lookup table and query this lookup table in your Kusto RLS policy. I just posted an answer how to integrate a lookup table into a RLS function here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78402329/in-azure-data-explorer-how-do-i-parametrize-metadata-to-be-used-in-row-level-sec/78422864#78422864)

@Werner that's definitely an interesting approach! Would also allow me to keep the tables as is and simply add a meta table for this information, thanks! Gonna give this a try
